# La diferencia entre “se te mueve” y “se mueve”

Tags: pronombres, reflexivos

“La clave de este ejercicio es que el vientre se te mueva con esfuerzo.”

¿Por qué se necesita **te**? **se mueve** ya está reflexivo...

Comment: ¡Interesante la pregunta, Fabiola!  // You are also welcome to ask questions in English, if that is more comfortable for you.  Either way works.

Answer (score 3):

El dativo de posesión o simpatético "te" permite inferir que se está hablando del vientre del interlocutor. Su ausencia vuelve la oración más impersonal ("el vientre de cualquier persona").

En español, es habitual que, en lugar de un adjetivo posesivo:

- La clave de este ejercicio es que **tu** vientre se mueva con esfuerzo.

se utilice el artículo definido y un dativo que hace referencia a la persona afectada:

- La clave de este ejercicio es que **el** vientre se **te** mueva con esfuerzo.

Nota 1: "moverse" no es reflexivo, porque el vientre no se mueve a sí mismo, sino por sí solo. Antiguamente se hablaba, en estos casos, de verbos "cuasirreflejos". Actualmente, se los conoce como "pronominales".

Nota 2: En [esta página](http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Dativos%20superfluos.htm) puede encontrarse una clasificación semántica bastante completa de los dativos.

Comment: Gracias. [“moverse" no es reflexivo, porque el vientre no se mueve a sí mismo, sino por sí solo]... Puede explicar más? No estoy muy claro...

Comment: Los verbos reflexivos son aquellos en los cuales hay identidad entre sujeto y objeto, por ejemplo "mirarse (al espejo)": uno mira y lo que se mira es uno mismo. En cambio, el vientre no se mueve a sí mismo. Simplemente se mueve. No existe el verbo "mover" intransitivo: uno mueve algo o se mueve (el verbo aquí es pronominal, "moverse"). ¿Qué idioma hablas, @Fabiola?

Comment: Hablo chino. :)    “...uno mueve algo o se mueve...”  pregunta: 1. ¿“se mueve”= voz pasiva?      2. Qué diferencia hay entre “a sí mismo” y “por si solo”?

Comment: "se mueve" no es voz pasiva. "a sí mismo" significa que la acción vuelve a quien la realiza. "por sí solo" significa que no se necesita ayuda para realizar la acción.

Comment: 1. (“...uno mueve algo o se mueve...”) SE MUEVE es impersonal?  Verbo impersonal siempre es verbo pronominal? Y si no es intransitivo, qué es el objeto?? 2.(por sí solo...no se necesita ayuda para realizar la acción) Entonces es una acción activa? El vientre hace la acción él mismo?

Comment: Los verbos impersonales son aquellos que sólo se conjugan en tercera persona del singular, como *llueve, truena, nieva, hace (frío), hay (gente)*. "se mueve" no es impersonal, pero sí pronominal e intransitivo (no tiene objeto). En el ejemplo en cuestión, no es pasivo sino activo. Puede ser pasivo si se entiende que alguien lo mueve: *El vientre se mueve (=es movido) con cuidado." (Alguien lo hace con cuidado.)

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain Gustavson's answer in English, in case that makes it clearer for you (and perhaps for others who might come across this question).

In English, one would use a possessive pronoun, and talk about "*your* belly."  But in Spanish, generally one doesn't do that -- instead, one uses the definite article, "el vientre."  So then, if we want to personalize that belly, and make it clear whom it belongs to, then we stick this little indirect pronoun in there: "Se te mueve el vientre | Your belly moves."

Here is another example:

> ¿Te duele mucho el brazo? | Does your arm hurt a lot?

Comment: Thank you! I do feel more comfortable reading English. :) More questions: (1) “moverse” is a pronominal verb? (2) Pronominal verb is siempre intransitivo? (3) I think “moverse” could also be seen as reflexivo since el vientre moves itself ---> do the action and receive the action, no?

Comment: I didn't learn "pronominal" -- I learned "reflexive."  But I *think* the answer to (1) is yes.  For (2), no.  For example, I gave myself a book for my birthday, *Me autoregalé para festejar mi cumpeaños.*  For (3), I'll refer you to what I put in my Answer.  Do you understand the *brazo* example I provided?