# Moverse (verbo pronombre)

Tags: pronombres

**“La clave de este ejercicio es que el vientre se te mueva con esfuerzo.”**

*"moverse" no es reflexivo, porque el vientre no se mueve a sí mismo, sino por sí solo.*

Preguntas:

1. No entiendo por qué dice “el vientre no se mueve a sí mismo, sino por sí solo.” No estoy muy claro sobre las diferencias aquí... El vientre mueve por sí mismo, no?
2. ¿Podria explicarme la definición acerca de “verbo pronombre” como “moverse” aquí? Cómo determinar si es “reflexivo” o “verbo prnl”?
3. ¿Puede decir 
   “La clave de este ejercicio es que el vientre mueva con esfuerzo” sin “**se te**”?   ¿Hay algunas diferencias en significados?

Answer (score 2):

Resulta más que evidente que OP no está satisfecho con la respuesta y los comentarios en [esta otra pregunta relacionada.](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/29073/la-diferencia-entre-se-te-mueve-y-se-mueve) Haré un nuevo intento.

El verbo "mover" sin objeto no existe (a menos que esté implícito o tácito, como por ejemplo al hacer referencia a los movimientos durante un juego de mesa: *Ahora muevo yo*). Podemos decir:

A. La clave de este ejercicio es que **(tú) muevas el vientre** con esfuerzo.

Pero, en respuesta a (3), **NO** podemos decir:

B. *La clave de este ejercicio es que **el vientre mueva** con esfuerzo.

Decimos que el vientre **se mueve**, **NO** que ***el vientre mueve**. Por eso decimos que, en su uso intransitivo (sin objeto), "moverse" es pronominal.

En respuesta a (2), el verbo es reflexivo cuando la acción recae sobre el mismo que la realiza. Existe gente (sobre todo adolescentes) que se autoagrede. Si decimos que:

- La paciente X **se cortó**.

significa que se cortó a sí misma, es decir, que utilizó deliberadamente un elemento cortante para autoagredirse. Aquí, el verbo "cortarse" es reflexivo, porque significa "cortarse a sí mismo".

En cambio, si la persona **se corta** accidentalmente, aquí el verbo no es reflexivo sino pronominal:

- Juana **se cortó** al caerse.

En respuesta a (1), podemos decir que Juana se cortó por sí sola, porque nadie la cortó, ni tampoco se cortó a sí misma. Simplemente, se cortó.

Comment: Hopefully between our two extensive answers the OP will get it from one of them

Answer (score 1):

Una cosa que suele confundir a muchos que aprenden el español es el hecho de que algunos verbos son, en efecto, obligatoriamente transitivos. En un idioma como el inglés, el verbo *move* es bien intransitivo (realizar movimiento de sí mismo) bien transitivo (cambiar el sitio de alguna cosa a otro). En el español ambos significados existen, pero no hay diferencia de transitividad para determinarlo.

Cuando un verbo obligatoriamente transitivo se usa sin objeto aparente, en castellano se emplea un pronombre reflexivo pero ojo: sin que represente una acción reflexiva. En estos casos, decimos que el verbo no es reflexivo, sino pronominal.

Que un verbo se puede usar de esta forma no le quita la posibilidad de usarse *también* como reflexivo, y creo que ahí está la confusión para algunos ya que a veces la línea entre los dos usos puede ser bastante fina. Pero tomemos un verbo como*quemar* que funciona de forma parecida.

- **¡Cuidado! ¡Eso quema!**
  Uso que parece intransitivo, *eso* le ocasionará quemaduras al que lo tocare. No obstante, como hay un complemento fuertemente implícito (quemará *algo*, ¿no?), no se suele considerar como intransitivo.
- **Yo quemé los papeles.**
  Uso transitivo. Los papeles se quedan quemados por mi acción.
- **La casa se quemaba mientras esperaban a los bomberos.**
  Uso pronominal. ¿Qué quema la casa? Nada, no enciende a nada. La casa simplemente estaba con llamas. (Ojo: una prueba de que no es un ejemplo de la pasiva refleja es que vale en primera y segunda persona también)
- **El activista se quemó en frente de todos.**
  Uso reflexivo. El activista quemó algo. ¿Qué quemó? A sí mismo.

Con *mover*, si digo que *me estoy moviendo*, digo que estoy gesticulando o habiendo movimientos. Si *me muevo*, se interpreta que estoy cambiando de lugar por mi volición. Pero si solo digo muevo, la gente pensará ¿pero *qué* estará moviendo ese tipo?

Por eso, hay que decir *se mueva* en tu ejemplo.  Lo de añadir *te* nos indica quién ha beneficiado por el movimiento (o, se supone en este caso, quien ha intentado hacer que se mueva).  Se dijésemos *te mueva*, ¡el vientre estaría causando que tú te mueves!

Comment: Escrito en el móvil, errores habrá

Comment: Gracias~ 1.( La casa se quemaba mientras...Uso pronominal.¿Qué quema la casa? Nada, no enciende a nada.) Este no es un verbo intransitivo ya que realizar movimiento de sí mismo??? 2. (Si me muevo...cambiando de lugar por mi volición) es un verbo intransitivo??  podría comprende como uso pronominal que [qué muevo yo? Yo misma?? ] ??

Comment: (No obstante, como hay un complemento fuertemente implícito (quemará algo, ¿no?), no se suele considerar como transitivo.) Es una errata? Debe ser intransitivo, no?

Comment: ¿Puede darme ejemplos con “mover” en vez de “quemar“?

Comment: Verbo pronominal es un verbo que hay que tener complemento directo pero lo oculta, y por eso se emplee un pronombre, ¿no? Que el pronombre funciona como gramático y no hay significado?

Comment: ¿Por qué dice (“La casa se quemaba mientras...Nada, no enciende a nada)
un uso pronominal? Parece no hay complemento implícito....

Comment: @Fabiola, perdona pero en tus comentarios es algo difícil ver donde empieza una cita o una pregunta.  Voy a intentar.  Sí, hubo un errata cuando dije *no se suele considerar como transitivo*.  Debí decir «intransitivo».  Al final di ejemplos con mover — *me estoy moviendo* frente a *me muevo*.  Luego sería **muevo **algo*** que podría ser un libro, cambiando su sitio.

Comment: En *la casa se quemaba* no hay complemento implícito porque hay un complemento explícito: *se* es un complemento.  (todo pronombre átono, *me te se le lo la*, etc, es complemento).  Decimos que es pronominal porque, a pesar de usar un pronombre reflexivo, no tiene un significado reflexivo: la casa no causó su propia situación de estar encendida, no es actor ni receptor de la acción en los sentidos que solemos dar a un sujeto u objeto directo.